# Como conectar um BD SQL Server no TOAD for Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, oracle

Utilizo o TOAD para gerenciar o BD Oracle 11g (BD principal) e preciso fazer a conexão de um BD SQL Server no TOAD do Oracle.

Eu preciso fazer uma chamada no SQL Server como por exemplo um SELECT só que dentro do Oracle (Toad for Oracle), entende?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a pagina do [fabricante do software](https://www.quest.com/br-pt/products/toad-for-oracle/), somente os clients/servidores de banco abaixo são suportado pelo **Toad for Oracle**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso, oque você está procurando é o Toad for Sql Server?, caso sim você pode realizar o download pelo próprio [site do fabricante.](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/)

O **Toad for sql server** suporta os seguintes Databases:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui realizar a conexão através do Link Server